# Is there an elegant way to combine multiple methods that have the same signature and the same method call?

Tags: c#, http, http-get

I am writing a class that is sending quite a few GET requests and I am looking for the right way to consolidate them. I have extracted the common logic into a method called GetRequest. Here is what it looks like at the moment:

```cs
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(string message)
{
    _uriBuilder.Path = _commonApiPath + message;
    return await _client.GetAsync(_uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetA()
{
    return await GetRequest("sys/a");
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetB()
{
    return await GetRequest("sys/b");
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetC()
{
    return await GetRequest("sys/c");
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetX()
{
    return await GetRequest("sys/x");
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetY()
{
    return await GetRequest("sys/y");
}
```

This approach is straightforward and it works, but is there some language feature that I am able to use in order to combine those calls? The only real difference is the string that is passed as the message. I don't want the consumer of this class to have to include the message string since it could be potentially written incorrectly.

I was considering trying to use Func<>/Action<> or lambdas to consolidate, but each one seems to have a limitation which makes me think it's not the correct approach.

Comment: What does this gain you over allowing the callers to directly call `GetRequest("sys/a")` instead of `GetA()`? Is it to constrain what strings might be passed? A Dictionary mapping an enum to a string lets you reasonably well articulate that only a fixed set of values can be used, if that's the requirement. If not, please explain what this is trying to gain?

Comment: Perhaps a switch case?

Comment: I agree with Damien - seems like a good match for an enum.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is correct. I am trying to constrain the consumer. I will explore the dictionary mapping approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is just to constrain the allowed values, expose an *enum* to the callers, then use a dictionary behind the scenes:

```
public enum RequestType {
  A,
  B,
  ...
}

private static readonly Dictionary<RequestType, string> RequestPaths = new Dictionary<RequestType, string> {
  { RequestType.A, "sys/a"},
  { RequestType.B, "sys/b"}
};

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(RequestType request)
{
    _uriBuilder.Path = _commonApiPath + RequestPaths[request];
    return await _client.GetAsync(_uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

This will throw at runtime if they cast an unknown value to `RequestType` but it usually suffices in keeping the honest callers honest.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative to using an enum and a dictionary is to use a class with a fixed set of static values:

```
public class RequestType
{
    public static RequestType A { get; } = new("sys/a");
    public static RequestType B { get; } = new("sys/b");
    ...
    public string Message { get; }
    private RequestType(string message) => Message = message; // Note private constructor
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(RequestType requestType)
{
    _uriBuilder.Path = _commonApiPath + requestType.Message ;
    return await _client.GetAsync(_uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

This is a little bit more flexible, since you can add some more data or logic to your RequestType if need be. But it also adds a bit more complexity that can make things like serialization more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was just thinking about how I could include PUT requests that require extra data into the scheme above, and this seems like a good solution to that question.